# Jquery: Alternative to building selector strings?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there an alternative to building selector strings in jquery?

In particular, I am trying to extract information from the labels of several form elements, so I need to create queries like `$('[for=#id]')`. It seems inelegant (and probably inefficient) to have to create the query strings on every pass of every iteration over the form elements.

The only similar question I can find is [jQuery (anti-)pattern: building selectors with string manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567496/jquery-anti-pattern-building-selectors-with-string-manipulation) which doesn't have any useful answers.

Comment: Well, you could select the label by it's location relative to the form element you are iterating through. For example, if the label immediately preceeds the form element, you could just use `element.prev()`

Comment: I'm having trouble with the context of what you want can you elaborate show me some html and what your trying to get at ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At-least limit the search to the form in which you are looking. Searching by attributes is in-efficient because you have to iterate over every element in the root set of elements. so instead of searching every element in the DOM, limit your search:

```
var forID = $('#my-form').find('[for=#id]');
```

You can make this a bit faster by searching for labels inside the form, then filtering down to just what you want:

```
var $allLabels = $('#my-form').find('label');

//then you can find a specific element by searching in the $allLabels object.
$allLabels.filter('[for="#id"]');
```

If your labels don't change dynamically then you should cache their selection outside of your loop; always cache values that do not change within the loop, outside of the loop.

Comment: Also, in that second line, is that correct syntax? If so, wonderful.

Comment: @Marcin I'm assuming you mean `var $allLabels = $('#my-form').find('label');`. That starts by selecting the form by id, which is very fast, then finds all the `label` elements in the form, which is also quite fast for browsers that have `getElementByTagName`, and these `label` elements are saved in the `$allLabels` variable for you to access later. Be aware that to find a single label or a group of labels within the `$allLabels` variable you need to use `.filter()` instead of `.find()` because you have a list of elements, not nested elements (`.find()` searches descendants).

Comment: No, I meant "Is `$allLabels.filter('[for="#id"]');` valid?" (I see that it is, and that answers exactly the question I was asking.)

Comment: Cool, looks like ya got it then. I recommend looking over the jQuery DOM Traversal Functions (you can select elements in a lot of ways with jQuery): http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/. If you find a type of selection you like, do a quick Google search for it plus the keywords "performance" to see how it performs. I generally run JSPerfs to see what's faster. Here's a demo of a JSPerf (this one tests the speed of some loops): http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loops/2

Answer (score 0):

If you always need to process each element every time, then you can simply do the query once and store the results in an variable.  Then, whenever you need to extract the information in those elements, you can iterate through everything in that variable, saving the need to query the list of elements each time.